# Как сделать,чтобы label двигался пропорционально родителю, при изменении его размера?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Devexpress 16.2
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var label1 = new LabelControl();
        label1.Location = imgRoom.PointToClient(MousePosition);  // changed here.
        label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        label1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        label1.BorderStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Simple;
        label1.Parent = imgRoom;
        label1.Text = "Point";
        imgRoom.Controls.Add(label1);
        contrl.Enqueue(label1);
    }
```

Я добавляю точку на `PictureEdit`, но после изменения размера формы точка начинает «плавать» по картинке. Как привязать label к конкретному месту?

Comment: Добавьте еще тип `imgRoom` (как объявлено поле?)

Comment: Поле было добавлено  с помощью ToolBox'a и этот инструмент называется  PictureEdit.

Comment: Странно. Вы уверены что после изменений плавает именно `label1` (а не надпись «нет картинки», например)? Создал простое приложение с `PictureEdit` и `label` закрепляется на месте.

Comment: В этом то и суть проблемы, что когда image box меняет свои размеры, то нужно, чтобы point  оставался с тем местом, в котором он был поставлен, а не "плавал" отдельно от imagebox'a.

Comment: Т.е. сейчас `label` стоит на месте, а нужно чтобы при изменении он передвигался пропорционально по картинке?

Comment: Всё правильно сказали.

Comment: Поправил ответ, проверьте его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить значение `AnchorStyles.None` свойству [`Control.Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), чтобы положение `label` изменялось пропорционально изменениям размера родителя:

```
label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

Из документации [`AnchorStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.anchorstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If a control has its Anchor property set to AnchorStyles.None, the control moves half of the distance that the container of the control is resized. For example, if a Button has its Anchor property set to AnchorStyles.None and the Form that the control is located on is resized by 20 pixels in either direction, the button will be moved 10 pixels in both directions.
>
> *Вольный перевод: Если свойству `Anchor` установлено значение `AnchorStyles.None`, то при изменении размера контейнера элемент управления сдвигается на половину изменения. Например, если у кнопки установлено значение `Anchor` равное `AnchorStyles.None` и если форма на которой находится кнопка изменяет размер на 20 пикселей в любых направлениях по горизонтали либо вертикал, то кнопка будет сдвинута на 10 пикселей в тех же направлениях.*

Если понадобится другая логика пропорционального изменения положения `label` то придется самому обрабатывать событие `Resize` у родителя.

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо вам за помощь :)